# Anything wrong with the loop - getting Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Just want to check if am doing something wrong here coz for small dataset the function works fine but a little more records and i get max executuion time error;

```
function getValue($products, $storeNum, $productKey) {
    foreach($products as $row)
    {
      if((int)$row->name === (int)$storeNum && (int)$row->product_key === (int)$productKey)
      {
        return $row->value;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input $products array is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => 0
            [name] => 3195
            [product_key] => 13                
        )

)
```

PS: Function getvalue() is being called in another loop that creates the matrix of 400 (stores as Y-axis) by 50 (product names X-axis)

Comment: Can you re-organize your products array so that it is indexed by (for example) `product_key` or perhaps even another layer for `name`?

Comment: How exactly will that help can you please elaborate ?

Comment: How many is _a little more records_???

Comment: I mean it can go up to few hundreds or max thousand but not too big I mean nothing in millions

Comment: At the moment you are looking through every record, if you index the array by `product_key` then you can access the data by that as a key - and then using `name` - so `$products[$productKey][$storeNum]`

Comment: @NigelRen Actually that is the way I need it for a matrix.

Comment: The actual function here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4aa6c80641eaea9b012160f3f22d427bb21464d6 only take `.11` seconds to search `100,000` records until the end.  What is your `max_execution_time ` set to?

Comment: It's 256M @AbraCadaver

Comment: I mis-typed `max_execution_time`

Comment: Where are these records coming from? Are you sure it's the loop that's slow, or could it be the query or whatever is producing `$products`?

Comment: It's 30 secs ... one more thing the function getvalue() is being called in another loop that creates the matrix of 400 (stores) by 50 (product names)

Comment: How do you call this function? In a loop?  That's where it probably is.  The 30 seconds is for the entire script and it probably just happens to be in the function when it hits 30.

Comment: @Don'tPanic the query is pretty quick no issues there ... it's in the loop. Like I said the function getvalue() is being called in another loop that creates the matrix of 400 (stores) by 50 (product names)

Comment: Do some baselining. Add `microtime`s and see what takes the execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling the `getValue` function 20000 times and iterating (worst case) the entire products array each time.

It should go much faster if you build the matrix in one iteration of `$products`. Here's a basic way to do that:

```
function makeMatrix($stores, $product_names, $products) {
    $matrix = [];

    // create the matrix from the lists of stores and product names
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        foreach ($product_names as $product_name) {
            $matrix[$store][$product_name] = 0;
        }
    }

    // fill the matrix with the list of products
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $matrix[$product->name][$product->product_key] = $product->value;
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

---

I think this should be faster because it runs as:

```
count(stores) * count(product_names) + count(products)
```

And my theory is that the way you're currently doing it runs as:

```
count(stores) * count(product_names) * triangular_number(count(products))
```

Comment: Well here is the thing ... I have list of stores as Y-axis and Product names as X-axis which are both from different tables, now from the products array (fetched from 3rd table) I need to show which store has how much quantity of each product, hope this will make things a bit clear.

Comment: Ah I see. This needs to be a little bit different then, but I think the general idea is the same. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @Just_Do_It I edited the answer based on your comment, I think that should work better if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Let me try it out :)

Comment: Well it returns 0 value for the entire matrix.

Comment: Hmm, so it isn't filling it with the values for some reason. That's odd. It works in theory: https://3v4l.org/grdGq

Comment: Based on how it works in this function, it seems like the only way it could have zero values for the entire matrix is if `$products` was empty. Even if it didn't match any of the previous keys in `$matrix` for some reason it would just add new keys.

Comment: I did check the dataset and there are values, works fine for the original matrix I had but when I update to the new one it's all 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man ... your solution working perfectly with little bit of twist :)

Answer (score 0):

If the $products array needs to maintain that specific format, here's the most efficient method to retrieve the product value from millions of records:

```
function getValue($products, $name, $productKey) {
    return ($search = explode('"name":' . $name . ',"product_key":' . $productKey, json_encode($products))) && (next($search) !== false) ? rtrim(substr($search[0], strrpos($search[0], '":') + 2), ',') : false;
}
```

Example product array:

```
$products = array(
    (object) array(
        'value' => 0,
        'name' => 13,
        'product_key' => 3195
    ),
    (object) array(
        'value' => 20,
        'name' => 14,
        'product_key' => 3196
    ),
    (object) array(
        'value' => 40,
        'name' => 15,
        'product_key' => 3197
    )
);
```

Retrieving a value with product name and key (returns false if no value is found):

```
$productValue = getValue($products, 14, 3196);
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot ...!

Comment: @Just_Do_It If the `name` and `product_key` keys aren't adjacent in your array, let me know and I'll modify the answer.

Comment: well the entire matrix is blank, nothing returned by the function.

Comment: Also like you asked name and product_key keys will be adjacent to each other.

Comment: @Just_Do_It If getvalue() is called from a different loop to create a matrix, can you edit the question to show how that function is used?